# Can't connect to a MongoDB using Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, connection

Can't connect to a MongoDB using Node.js.

This is my code (mdb.js):

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient, format = require('util').format;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:3000', function(err,db){

    if(err){
         throw err;
    } else {
         console.log("Connected");
    }
    db.close();
});
```

node mdb.js prints MongoError:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuWK6.png)

Comment: How are you starting mongo?

Comment: If you're using macOS, maybe it's because you're using localhost instead of 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 16):

it worked for me when i changed 'localhost' to 127.0.0.1

Comment: Are you on a system with IPv6 enabled, and mongo is only listening on 127.0.0.1, not ::1?  `netstat -an | grep LISTEN` (or your OS's equivalent) will show more information.

Comment: Same is the case for me! Do you know why this is the case?

Answer (score 5):

change 'localhost' to 127.0.0.1

```
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');
const url = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017';
const client = new MongoClient(url);
const database = 'ecomm';

async function getData()
{
  let result = await client.connect();
  let db = result.db(database);
  let collection = db.collection('products');
  let response = await collection.find({}).toArray();
  console.log(response);
}

getData();
```

Comment: But, most importantly, _why_?

Comment: Here's the reasoning: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/getting-error-while-connecting-to-mongodb-using-node-js/216431

Answer (score 1):

Your error explaining itself. 
Mongo cant find default db path `B:/data/db`.

Create this folder or on start up choose another DB directory

```
mongod --dbpath yourPath(C:\myDb)
```

Also default mongo port is `27017` so you need to change connection string like this `"mongodb://@localhost:27017/dbYouWant"`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. It starts, but with many, many messages. Test script is also runs normally. I don't have any particular DB, that's why I cannot check it.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your MongoDB server is running by running `mongod` in the directory that MongoDB is installed.

Then see what port it is running on ( usually it's 27017 ) . Then update your URL in your code and you're good to go .

Answer (score 0):

Use this URL `mongodb://0.0.0.0:3000`

Answer (score 0):

First of all please verify that have you changed your default database port from 27017 to 3000 or not.
If not changed then please try the below code it's working for me

```
 const { MongoClient } = require("MongoDB");

 // Connection URL
 const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
 const client = new MongoClient(URL);

 // Database Name
 const dbName = "myProject";

 async function main() {
    // Use connect method to connect to the server
    await client.connect();
    console.log("Connected successfully to server");
    const db = client.db(dbName);
    const collection = db.collection("documents");

    // return "done.";
 }

main()
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error)
  .finally(() => client.close());
```

Also here is I attached a my screenshot with the output
[Sample output example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReejT.png)

Answer (score 0):

By using `0.0.0.0` instead of `localhost` in windows solves the problem,
`mongodb://0.0.0.0:port/db_name`.

For example:

```
mongodb://0.0.0.0:3000/test_db
```

Answer (score 0):

'mongodb://0.0.0.0:3000'  try to make it this it will work in the new version